# How to get rank in mysql for below dataset?

Tags: mysql

Based on below data set, how to get rank in next column?

```
  create table testrank(column_val varchar(10), rank_val integer);

  insert into testrank(column_val)
  values
  ('OH3'),
  ('OH3'),
  ('IH3'),
  ('OH1'),
  ('OH1'),
  ('IH1'),
  ('IH1'),
  ('IH3'),
  ('IH3'),
  ('OH3'),
  ('OH3'),
  ('OH3'),
  ('OH3');

  Expected result
  column    Rank
   OH3       3
   OH3       3
   IH3       3
   OH1       2
   OH1       2
   IH1       2
   IH1       2
   IH3       1
   IH3       1
   OH3       1
   OH3       1
   OH3       1
   OH3       1
```

I can see the data pattern is little different. In this case order of data should not change.

Answer (score 1):

Insert values for the column rank_val then you can list the rank by using the following query

```
select column_val as column,rank_val as rank from testrank;
```

You can use the following query for ordering your output

```
select column_val as column,rank_val as rank from testrank order by rank_val desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the question. Do you mean this?

```
SELECT column_val,
       rank_val AS Rank
FROM   testrank;
```

If you want to order it, you can use `ORDER BY <expression> [ASC|DESC]`
If that doesn't help, please describe what you want to achieve and what you tried

Comment: @datavadar : first column is the value and second column is the rank(which i have to populate using sql code)

Comment: And what do you want to do? Select it with a specific order? Add a column with calculated values? Something else?

Comment: sir i'm saying that i have a column name 'column_val', i want to display the rank for this column using sql code, the rank of the order should match in given manner in (rank_val), this should be generated using sql code.

Comment: By 'rank for this column' you mean the value in "rank_val", the absolute position within the output or what?
Can you post an example of what you get and what you want to get?

Comment: I don't understand this one either.
Why do 'OH3' and 'IH3' have a rank of 1 at the end of your result and one of 3 at the start?

Comment: Its becase i'm getting data in this order:OH3 and IH3 has to display in one block if you reading from the bottom then IH1 and OH1 has to go in one block and then in the last IH3 and OH3 has to go in one block, here i can not change the order of the data,
so later when i m writing the care condition i can take each block in every case condition based in given rank 1,2, 3.

Comment: I still don't get it. In your example 'OH3' has rank 1 and 3 for no obvious reason. If it's based on the order, I don't get why some ranks exist more than once. Can you provide a formula or something? I literally have no clue what you could possibly mean at this point.